# Jenkins build says successful but no output is seen

Tags: shell, jenkins

My Jenkins build job indicates success but none of the scripts I am executing seem to do anything. I put a simple "pwd" command to echo current working directory but nothing happens. All Jenkins reports is "Running shell script" and then nothing is seen.

Snippet of Jenkins log:

```
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[Pipeline] sh
[an_example_test3-26UQSYQ445FSBP4QRKEWLPQCJH545MLQVD6B552CIGPOXLZO4G5A] Running shell script
[Pipeline] sh
[an_example_test3-26UQSYQ445FSBP4QRKEWLPQCJH545MLQVD6B552CIGPOXLZO4G5A] Running shell script
[Pipeline] sh
[an_example_test3-26UQSYQ445FSBP4QRKEWLPQCJH545MLQVD6B552CIGPOXLZO4G5A] Running shell script
[Pipeline] sh
[an_example_test3-26UQSYQ445FSBP4QRKEWLPQCJH545MLQVD6B552CIGPOXLZO4G5A] Running shell script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Jenkinsfile that is used to define the builds:

```
node {
stage 'build'
sh "echo  ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
git url: 'git@hd1:testing', branch: "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
sh "ls -rtl"
sh "pwd"
sh "csh  ${workspace}/simple.csh"
sh "csh  ${workspace}/source.csh"
}
```

Comment: Can you see the jenkins report? I mean if you are using any report plugin you can see if the tests are passed or skipped or failed. I think probability all the tests are skipped, and showing the green build

Comment: I logged in as Jenkins user and did some looking around. Actually, the scripts are expected to create certain log and executables. I don't find any of them. All I see is the files that are checked out from Git.